# Rails3 Controllers Plural / Singular Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some issues with a controller in my rails3 application that is called nas

My ruby app is connected to an existing DB so the table name has to stay as nas.

In my models, I have previously been able to do this:

```
set_table_name
```

But I don't know how to do this in my controller / routes.

Right now, my routes contains this:

```
resources :nas
```

And the output is:

```
        new_na GET    /nas/new(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"nas"}
       edit_na GET    /nas/:id/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"nas"}
            na GET    /nas/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"nas"}
               PUT    /nas/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"nas"}
               DELETE /nas/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"nas"}
```

As you can see, rails drops the 's'

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty confusing because I have no idea what a "na" or "nas" is. From your question I have the idea that you always want to refer to it as "nas", both plural and singular.

If that's the case, then the answer is to put this in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable "nas"
end
```

This will also make your `Nas` model use the `nas` table by default, so no need for `set_table_name`.

However note that there is no reason to use `Nas` for your controllers if you don't want to! You can name them anything you like, as long as this is reflected in `routes.rb` and you use the correct model in your controller.

Comment: thanks so much for this. this is also what i did for a couple of classes of mine named "livestock" and "equipment", both of which are spelled the same whether plural or singular (no 's' needed). If anyone would like to see the effect of adding this line to inflections.rb, run a fake scaffolding such as `rails g scaffold equipment -p`, the `-p` allows you to preview the files and their names without actually creating them. you can see the how the names of files change after adding or commenting out the inflect.uncountable line. awesome.

Answer (score 2):

A guess, maybe you should try overriding the naming convention, because 'nas' is not plural? (assuming that's why the s dropped)

```
# Inflection rule
Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'nas', 'nases'
end
```

in `environment.rb`

**Edit:** Instead of `environment.rb` use: `config/initializers/inflections.rb` (thanks [Benoit Garret](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211840/benoit-garret))

Comment: I prefer to put my inflections in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`. And you can also put it as an uncountable: `inflect.uncountable "nas"`.

Answer (score 2):

> My ruby app is connected to an existing DB so the table name has to stay as nas.

Then why do your routes/controllers also have to be named `nas`? Once you fixed it on your model-level everything should be fine.

```
# model.rb
class WhateverILikeToCallMyModel
  set_table_name "nas"
end

# controller.rb
class WaynesController << ApplicationController
  # ...

  def index
    @items = WhateverILikeToCallMyModel.all
  end
end

# routes.rb
resources :waynes
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.rb, try,

```
match '/nas', :to => 'na'
```

Comment: Is there no way to retain the s?

Comment: OK, you could try this, but beware of the implications for other tables.  ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false